# rails uninitialized constant Module Name

Tags: ruby-on-rails, autoload

I have an integrations folder under app directory.
I can see that this path is loaded

```
 ActiveSupport::Dependencies.autoload_paths
 "/appname/app/integrations"
```

then inside this path I have another folder with a nested module

```
"/appname/app/integrations/moduleA/base_service.rb"
# frozen_string_literal: true

module Integrations
  module ModuleA
    class BaseService
```

But when I am trying to use the class

```
Integrations::moduleA::BaseService
::Integrations::moduleA::BaseService
```

both of them giving me

```
NameError: uninitialized constant Integrations
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The way the rails autoloader works (both the classical and [Zeitwerk](https://github.com/fxn/zeitwerk#custom-root-namespaces)) is that the immediate subdirectories of the `/app` folder are "root" directories. That means that the autoloader will look for root level constants in all of these directories.

Thus if you want to define `Foos::Bar` you would need to place the file in `app/foos/foos/bar.rb`.

If you want to avoid that and place the constant in `app/integrations/module_a/base_service.rb` you would need to push the directory with a custom namespace to Zeitwerk:

```
loader.push_dir(Rails.root.join('app', 'integrations'), namespace: Integrations)
```

With the classic autoloader the solution was to add the `/app` folder to the autoloading/eager_loading paths as a root as well.

```
config.autoload_paths += %W(#{config.root}/app)
```

So that the autoloader will look for `Integrations::ModuleA` in `app/integrations/module_a.rb`.

See:

- [Autoloading and Reloading Constants (Zeitwerk Mode)](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/autoloading_and_reloading_constants.html)
- [Autoloading and Reloading Constants (Classic Mode)](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/autoloading_and_reloading_constants_classic_mode.html)

Comment: you have a great way of explaining things

Comment: Thank you @JoelBlum thats very kind.